# Could not open URL... No Activity found to handle Intent

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation, navigation-drawer, deep-linking

I'm trying to apply deep linking in my react native app. I followed the documentation and when trying to do the first test I had some problems, I believe it's because of using stack navigator and drawer menu.

Stack:

```
const SignedInStack = () => (
  <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen name='Confluence' component={Confluence} />
    <Stack.Screen name='QRCode' component={Main} />
    <Stack.Screen name='Notifications' component={Notifications} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
)
```

DrawerMenu:

```
const DrawerMenu = () => (
  <Drawer.Navigator
    screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}
    drawerContent={(props) => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />}
  >
    <Drawer.Screen
      name="SignedInStack"
      component={SignedInStack}
    />
  <Drawer.Navigator/>
);
```

App.js:

```
const App = () => (
  <NavigationContainer linking={{
    prefixes: ['example://'],
    config: {
      screens: {
        Notifications: 'notifications',
      },
    },
  }}>
    <DrawerMenu />
  </NavigationContainer>
);
```

My first useEffect on initial screen of my stack:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    Linking.openURL('example://app/notifications');
  }, []);
```

Right after trying to redirect to the notifications screen I get the following error message:
*"Error: Could not open URL 'example://app/notifications': No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=example://app/notifications flg=0x10000000 }"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `Linking.openURL` I used [linkTo](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-link-to), as in the example below:

```
import { useLinkTo } from '@react-navigation/native';
...
const linkTo = useLinkTo();

useEffect(() => {
  linkTo('/notifications');
}, []);
```